# Is there an equivalent to numpy where() but with the condition evaluated sequentially rather than as a bool map before selection?

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, open3d

I'm creating an elevation map from a point cloud. When I project the point cloud on to the elevation map there may be multiple points that project to the same cell. I only want the point with highest height in each cell.

I have my elevation map as a (J,K) size float type numpy array named image. The cells in the image that need to be updated are in a (2,N) array named pix_points. And my heights are in a (1,N) array. My initial attempt at implementing this operation looks like:

```
    image[pix_points[1,:], pix_points[0,:]] = (
    np.where(
        image[pix_points[1,:], pix_points[0,:]] <= heights,
        heights, 
        image[pix_points[1,:], pix_points[0,:]]))
```

I thought this would work but it seems that the condition in where is evaluated first and with that bool map then chooses between heights or the existing value at that location. This behaviour can't deal with repeated image locations with different heights, as it needs to first write in a location and then later on (within the same pass) check if the same location is higher than another height and update accordingly. I don't want to use a python loop to implement this. Is there any way of doing what I intend in a vectorized way?

UPDATE

As requested the python loop code for the described operation is just:

```
for p, h in zip(pix_points.T, heights):
    if image[p[1],p[0]] <= h:
        image[p[1],p[0]] = h
```

This is actually faster than I thought it would be. For N being about half a million it takes about 1.75s. I've been using the python loop version for smaller point coulds and it's fine. Although I'd like to speed it up as it's part of a live system, where the point clouds come from a camera live stream. I see I'd probably have to rewrite it in cython or c++ if I want to get a further speed up. I just wanted to make sure there isn't a numpy way (or other python library way) of doing this first, as I'm not too fluent writing cython or C++ python bindings.

Comment: how about using a non-python loop, you should be able to use cython or numba to get something close to a vectorized loop performance, as i don't see this being done in a vectorized way without consuming too much memory (ie: creating a 3D grid and using amax on the Z dimension)

Comment: It is not clear to me why the evaluation of the boolean array is a problem. Can you show an example of Python loop so the operation can be more clear?

Comment: This needs a [mcve], example and working code (iterative if necessart).  for clarity, and stesting.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing there is no obvious numpy way of doing what I want and following Ahmed AEK suggestion, I've rewritten the loop in cython and got about a 100 times speed up. For reference I put here my implementation update_elevation_map.pyx

```
#cython: profile=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: initializedcheck=False
#cython: nonecheck=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def update_elevation_map(
        np.float32_t[:, :] image,
        np.int64_t[:, :] pix_points,
        np.float32_t[:] heights):
        
    cdef np.int64_t[:] p
    cdef np.float32_t h
    cdef int N = heights.shape[0]
    cdef int i

    for i in range(N):
        p = pix_points[:,i]
        h = heights[i]
        if image[p[1],p[0]] <= h:
            image[p[1],p[0]] = h

    return np.asarray(image)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="update_elevation_map", ext_modules=cythonize('update_elevation_map.pyx'),)
```

and built with the command:

```
python3 setup.py  build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: Note `i` should be declared as a `cdef` too so the loop to be faster.